# Filter by values from csv file in Tableau

Tags: csv, filter, tableau-api

I've get a dimension in my Tableau workbook called discount codes. This dimension holds 30,000 strings. Also I've get separate csv files that hold hundreds of discount codes.
In Tableau I want to filter out the values from a single csv file.
I have tried to create a filter and just paste the discount codes in a list:

[image]

When I select every single value manually it works. But when I paste the whole list Tableau can't match the discount codes.

Is there any way to filter the values without selecting every single value?

Comment: You can use `IN` operator.  Build a statement in text editor or directly from csv.  However i am not sure about processing speed in this case as you have very large number of codes!

Comment: You could also see if you can find a clever way to express your constraint as a join. If so, that could be very efficient. If your list of codes was the ones you wanted to KEEP, it would be a trivial left join. Since it is the opposite, finding an efficient join clause may be tricky, but worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Excel (for speed) and a calculated field. Use Excel to write the calculated field formula. You already have the list of discount codes in Excel, use this to create a calculated field, a giant CASE statement.

Assuming your list of exclusions starts in cell A1, cell B1 would be

```
="WHEN '"&A1&'" THEN 1 "
```

The formula in cell B2:

```
=B1 & "WHEN '"&A2&'" THEN 1 "
```

Drag that formula to the end, and you should then have the contents of a large case statement. Copy the final cell formula as values, then copy the text into a Tableau calulcated field.

Start the calculated field with:

```
CASE [Discount Codes]
*pasted value*
END
```

All being well, you can use that calculated field as a data source filter and exclude 1.

Note I haven't tested this so watch out for bracket errors, etc.